# Does runtime Sphinx need the conf file?

Tags: sphinx

If I create run my conf file on my index can Sphinx search then run w/o the conf file or associated wordforms for user search or are those files still needed for reference? My understanding so far is that when you process the index with rotate the .idx itself contains all that information needed? Basically trying to release production version of the search and not expose the config/wordforms on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the config file on the server, it contains some important stuff.

(like getting the list of indexes, and the folder to load them from. As well as log files, pid file paths etc)

... you could perhaps get away with having a simplified config file, that doesnt list all of the settings for the index. Just the name and path would probably be enough. As the rest would be read from the .sph file.

BUt as they .sph file is on the server, the config can be recreated from it, so by not providing a config file, you just making it slightly harder to access the index config, not impossible.

... small wordform files may be embedded in the index file for simplicity, but if the file is big, searchd will load it direct from the file. (only the path stored in the sph file)

Honestly dont see what you hope to gain by being secretative about the index data. Its in the index files anyway.

Comment: Ah I see so just accessing the .idx file will have it as well.

Comment: Well I have a lot of 'proprietary' indexing going on that also reveals a good part of my db not to mention some in-depth wordform files. So my hope was to remove those from the live server and just have either no cfg or a simple one that lists the core settings for the index.

Comment: Well I suppose the 'source' section definitely doesn't need to be there. Although the attributes/fields etc would be in the index. I think *everything* in the 'index' section is pretty much duplicated, so not worth omitting that. Ommitting the wordforms, is a non-starter, sphinx needs the full list to run queries anyway.