# Deploying Sphinx in Production

Tags: sphinx

Once I have rotated my index, do I need to keep my original sphinx.cfg file on my production server? In other words is it used at all during sphinxql queries? Can I for security purposes (proprietary data) remove that file until I am ready to rotate again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does runtime Sphinx need the conf file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808942/does-runtime-sphinx-need-the-conf-file)

Comment: @barryhunter Yes I realized that after reviewing my old questions I can remove/delete sorry/thanks.